# Ext4 filesystem corrupted overnight

Tags: filesystem, ssd, ext4

I've been using ubuntu 16.04 on a new ssd drive for 4 months, and so far I'd had no problems. But last night I left my computer on and when I woke up this morning, everything was read-only. I run `dmesg` and found this:

```
[259275.406148] EXT4-fs error (device sdb6): ext4_iget:4795: inode #6601521: comm unity-settings-: bogus i_mode (0)
[259275.407063] Aborting journal on device sdb6-8.
[259275.407831] EXT4-fs (sdb6): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

I googled what happened and found almost nothing, so it would seem that I've run into something strange. I rebooted my computer, but it got stuck in the following state:

[image: boot screen]

I then run `fsck /dev/sdb6` (this is were `/` is installed) and I got asked a lot of questions, and answered yes to all of them. I then rebooted again and now everything seems to be going ok.

My questions are: 
What could have caused this problem?
Is there any check I can perform to assure that it is not a hardware problem? 
Is there any way to tell whether I lost any files due to all this? (I checked `/lost+found` and found it empty).

Comment: https://blog.algolia.com/when-solid-state-drives-are-not-that-solid/ I had some similar issues that stopped after I removed the trim job from etc/cron.weekly

Comment: It is not proofed, but it looks like, that there is serious problem with SSD driver bounded with SSD (NVMe) technology and newer newer updates of driver. Actually, I don't know, how to solve this problem except don't use NVMe SSD connected straightforward to  the bus (M.2 type).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year since this incident. I kept using using the same Ubuntu 16.04 (without reformatting). At least I can say that I've not had this problem again. So, if anyone is panicking at this as I did a year ago, there is a chance that a single `fsck /dev/sdb6` will solve the issue and you will not run into it again.