# ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, raid, ext4, mdadm

The computer was working fine until this morning I found out the hdd (two 4TB disk in RAID0 made with `mdadm`) had Input/output error.

Upon `ls`ing the directory, I was met with:

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

And further inspection on dmseg shows that accessing my disk md127 causes some warnings and errors:

```
[5789751.027967] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027970] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027973] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #161822641: lblock 7: comm cp: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027975] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027976] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027979] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027982] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027986] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027987] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #161822641: lblock 7: comm cp: error -5 reading directory block
[5789751.027989] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): htree_dirblock_to_tree:994: inode #184288528: lblock 2: comm rg: error -5 reading directory block
```

Reading up on this, I found several articles on fixing this by doing `fsck` (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04).

- [Ext4 filesystem corrupted overnight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945914/ext4-filesystem-corrupted-overnight)
- [EXT4-fs error on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224673/ext4-fs-error-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I also found someone having the [same issue](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/critical-ssd-raid0-bug-under-kernel-4-0-0-4-0-1-4-0-2-and-3-18-14-a-4175543131/) with them using RAID0 disk (but a very long time ago since it's kernel 4.0.0).

My disk seems healthy since the output of `smartctl` reads `PASSED`. And `inode` seems to be functioning since there is still a lot left (only used 7% of inodes).

What could be the cause of this spontaneous failure? I would like to know since I want to know how I could prevent it or be ready for it next time it happens.

Currently, I'm still copying over non-corrupted files, but I'm planning to fix it by `fsck`.

Comment: This is a hardware error that may be corrected by running `fsck`. Go on backing up as much as possible, and then run `fsck`.

Comment: Yeah, everyone who had these types of errors uses `fsck` and magically this issue goes away. I was just wondering what is the cause of it and how I could prevent it in the future so that I wouldn't have to go through this _hell_ again... lost so many important files so

Comment: There is some redundancy built into a hard drive. That means that you can use a program like `fsck` to retrieve data from "bad blocks", i.e. areas on the drive that are physically damaged. Moreover, the `fsck` program will move the rescued data elsewhere, and keep a list of blocks that are found to be "bad" and are not to be used again.

Comment: ah I see, I didn't know you could also do that with `fsck`. Thanks for the help!